# Google Sheet Scrip Replace Spaces In A String

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble getting my script to work on even one column. I have similar scripts with the same loop doing other things, so I'm guessing I'm not using .replace() correctly.

In the debugger, my column data looks like this:

Input:
1 A
2 DATA ENGINEER
3 PROJECT MANAGER
4 DATA ANALYST
5 DESKTOP SUPPORT
6 CLOUD ENGINEER
7 CLOUD ENGINEER

Output:
1  A
2 DATA_ENGINEER
3 PROJECT_MANAGER
4 DATA_ANALYST
5 DESKTOP_SUPPORT
6 CLOUD_ENGINEER
7 CLOUD_ENGINEER

```
 function formatText() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A")
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] != "") {
      values[i][0] = values[i][0].replace(" ","_");
    }
    else
    {
      continue;
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values);
  debugger;
};
```

Comment: please specify the required output and input to the function clearly

Comment: are `values[i][0]` strings?

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes they are strings.

Comment: then what's the problem? your output looks correct

Comment: Apologies, @JaromandaX. That is my desired output. Nothing happens when I run the script.

Comment: what is output in the console if you `console.log(values[i][0])` before `if (values[i][0] != "") {` ... do you get the expected INPUT?

Comment: @JaromandaX, I'm in the Google project editor, so not too familiar with logging. I used Logger.log() and it returned the following:`[17-09-28 22:26:31:846 CDT] [[DATA_ENGINEER], [PROJECT_MANAGER], [DATA_ANALYST], [DESKTOP_SUPPORT], [PLATFORM_ENGINIEER], [CLOUD_ENGINEER], [AUTOMATION_ENGINEER], [DATABASE_ADMINISTRATOR], [SYSTEMS_ENGINEER], [SYSTEMS_ADMINISTRATOR], [INFRASTRUCTURE_ENGINEER], [MACHINE_LEARNING_ENGINEER], [HARDWARE_ENGINEER], [RELIABILITY_ENGINEER], [DATA_WAREHOUSE_ENGINEER], [ROBOTICS_ENGINEER], [AUGMENTED_VIRTUAL_REALITY_ENGINEER], []...`

Comment: that suggests `values[i][0]` isn't a string, looks like an array of NOT strings

Comment: debugger shows that values[i][0] are strings. Here is a screenshot from my Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqenvxfuxidxxi2/Screen%20Shot%202017-09-28%20at%2010.29.39%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Thank you for your help, @JaromandaX. I discovered that `var range` had a length of zero and the loop was not working. I changed to `for (i=0; i < values.length; i++)` and it is working now.